# Axios API calls are not working after deploying the web application on Heroku - MERN Application

Tags: node.js, api, heroku, mern, http-status-code-503

Before uploading my code to Heroku, my API calls worked just fine. However, it returns a status code of `503 (Service Unavailable)` after deployment.
This is my code

#### app.js file in my root folder (server file)

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(() => console.log("Connected to db!")).catch(dbErr => console.log(dbErr));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/post-result", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.val);
    const newSurvey = new survey({ surveyValues: req.body.val });


    await newSurvey.save()
        .then(data => {
            res.send(newSurvey);
            console.log(newSurvey);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});

app.get("/results", async (req, res) => {
    const result = await survey.find({});
    res.send(result);
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build")));
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    })
} else {
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.send("API running");
    })
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log("Listening on PORT 8080"));
```

#### My react file, where the API calls were made

```
const handleFormSubmit = async (e, val) => {
    const { data } = await Axios.post("/post-result", { val });
}
```

#### package.json file

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.12"
  }
}
```

**Error log in the console**
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 503 at e.exports createError.js:16) at e.exports (settle.js:17) at XMLHttpRequest.S (xhr.js:66)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 :

Maybe you should try using all the url instead of Axios.post("/post-result",{..}) You can use local variable to determine if you are in Prod or in local environment, create in util folder a file called for example baseUrl.js :

```
 const baseUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? "https://[your url used in port]"
    : "http://localhost:[your port]";
export default baseUrl;
```

And then import baseUrl in your folder and replace your Axios request by :

```
 const { data } = await Axios.post(baseUrl + "/post-result", { val });
```

Option 2 :

Also I noticed that you don't allow any URL in Cors Options :

```
let corsOptions = {
  origin: ["URL ALLOWED", ...],
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works!

Comment: Welcome, good luck !